# jquery not working until debugged using firebug

Tags: jquery, debugging, firebug

I am having a strange problem, a part of jquery code is not working properly until I add breakpoint in firebug, this is the code

```
    function loadPreviousGameCount() {

        var $hdnTotalPreviousGamesCount = $('#<%=hdnTotalPreviousGamesCount.ClientID %>');

        // load page count only if it is not already loaded
        if ($hdnTotalPreviousGamesCount.val() == "-1") {
            $.post('MypageUrl&MemberId=<%=MemberId%>',
            {},
            function(response) {
                if (response.IsDone) {
                    $hdnTotalPreviousGamesCount.val(response.Data);
                } else {
                    $hdnTotalPreviousGamesCount.val(response.Message);
                }
            }, 'json');
        }
    }
```

and I am using this function to intiate paging

```
function initPagination() {

   loadPreviousGameCount();

   // I put breakpoint on the below line("var pageCount...")
   var pageCount = parseInt($('#<%=hdnTotalPreviousGamesCount.ClientID %>').val());

   // Create pagination element              
   $("#divPager").show().pagination(pageCount,
                   {
                      callback: loadPreviousGames,
                      num_edge_entries: 1,
                      items_per_page: 5
                   });
}
```

So what I am trying to do is, I am loading games count from server and saving it to a hidden field if it is not already been loaded, and that games count I am using for pagination.
The code is working perfectly but only either from the second time or if I put a debug point in the very first time.

So I find the value written in hidden field inside initPagination function in two cases

1. In the second call of initPagination function.
2. If I put a debug point on the line I mentioned above in the first call.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

you need to call  `initPagination()` function after the responce from server.

```
$.post('MypageUrl&MemberId=<%=MemberId%>',
            {},
            function(response) {
                if (response.IsDone) {
                    $hdnTotalPreviousGamesCount.val(response.Data);
                } else {
                    $hdnTotalPreviousGamesCount.val(response.Message);
                }
            initPagination();

            }, 'json');
```

what is happening here is may be you are calling the function before loading the data. When you have a debug point it will delay sometime which enables the response to come before your  function call.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've introduced some sort of race condition. I would start by analyzing your server requests and responses. You might want to add the initialize call to the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Solved it like this, I know this is not the correct way but have started working 
I have removed loadPreviousGamesCount() function completely

```
 function initPagination() {

            var $hdnTotalPreviousGamesCount = $('#<%=hdnTotalPreviousGamesCount.ClientID %>');
            if ($hdnTotalPreviousGamesCount.val() == "-1") {
                $.post('<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/AjaxPageRequestHandler.aspx") %>?class=imLeagues.Web.Members.Pages.BO.Member.MemberGamesBO&method=GetMemberPreviousGamesCount&MemberId=<%=MemberId%>',
                {},
                function(response) {
                    if (response.IsDone) {

                        $hdnTotalPreviousGamesCount.val(response.Data);

                        // Create pagination element              
                        $("#divPager").show().pagination(response.Data,
                                            {
                                                callback: loadPreviousGames,
                                                num_edge_entries: 1,
                                                items_per_page: 5
                                            });

                    } else {
                        $hdnTotalPreviousGamesCount.val(response.Message);
                    }
                }, 'json');
            }
            else {
                // Create pagination element
                $("#divPager").show().pagination($hdnTotalPreviousGamesCount.val(),
                                            {
                                                callback: loadPreviousGames,
                                                num_edge_entries: 1,
                                                items_per_page: 5
                                            });
            }
        }
```